# React render not working with createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My simple component:

```
var AddProductForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <form >
                <input type='text' placeholder='lablbalbalbal'/>
            </form>
        )
    }
})
```

My second component that I want to 'render' the first component in some determined div via onClick:

```
var HeaderAction = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}  className="btn border-slate text-slate-800 btn-flat"><i className={this.props.icon + " position-left"}></i>{this.props.name}</button>
        )
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        var component = React.createElement(this.props.action.component);
        ReactDOM.render( component, document.getElementById('content'));
    }
})
```

When I click my 'HeaderAction' component, an error occurs:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid tag:

The console.log() from my 'component' :

```
Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "<AddProductForm/>", key: null, ref: null, props: Object…}
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
_owner: null
_self: null
_source: null
_store: Object
key: null
props: Object
ref: null
type: "<AddProductForm/>"
__proto__: Object
```

If in the render call I change '`component`' for "`<AddProductForm/>`" it works fine, but using the createElement for instantiate the object before the render doesn't.

Comment: What is `this.props.action.component`? At the time the render fails?

Comment: this.props.action.component resolves to a string, no fails.

Answer (score 4):

```
var AddProductForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <form >
                <input type='text' placeholder='lablbalbalbal'/>
            </form>
        )
    }
})

var HeaderAction = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}</button>
        )
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        var component = React.createElement(AddProductForm);
        ReactDOM.render( component, document.getElementById('content'));
    }
})
var mount = document.getElementById('container');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HeaderAction), mount)
```

I do not have an answer for you, however this seems to work. I do not know what `this.props.action.component` is in your case. I have created a small fiddle. Maybe we can work this out. https://jsfiddle.net/walkerrsmith/htaca7fa/

Comment: In my case,  **this.props.action.component** is dynamically passed string which references what sub component should I render. The problem is that somehow the createElement can't instance the correct element, passing 'HeaderAction ' or even '<HeaderAction />

Comment: This may be useful. Keep reading past the first couple of responses. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365. Maybe the comment https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365#issuecomment-163397564 helps

Comment: Walker is correct. `React.createElement` can take a string of a common element tag, or the class object of the react component. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html

Comment: @CHBuckingham ...furthermore, if you mistakenly provide a string instead of the class object, React will attempt to render a tag with that name instead of your shiny component. Silently. This happened to me, because I had to start the rendering somewhere I could not use JSX, and didn't know how to do it properly.